# Avoid concurrency in MERGE INTO statement db2

Tags: concurrency, db2

In a single SQL statement/transaction I need to:

1. check the existence of a certain row based on a condition
2. update-or-insert the row
3. select the value of the row

The execution of these steps must be atomic (so once I started with phase 1, no other transactions must execute step 2 or 3)

I kinda find a way using MERGE INTO and LOCK TABLE statement and, but my concern it's the step between 2 and 3.

phase 1-2:

```
lock table DOC_COUNT in exclusive mode;
MERGE INTO DOC_COUNT AS mt USING (
SELECT * FROM TABLE (
VALUES 
(?SEND_VALUE?, ?RECEIVE_VALUE?,1)
)
) AS vt (SEND, RECEIVE, QTY) ON (mt.SEND = vt.SEND AND mt.RECEIVE = vt.RECEIVE)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET QTY = mt.QTY + 1
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (SEND, RECEIVE, QTY) VALUES (vt.SEND, vt.RECEIVE, (SELECT COUNT(DOCUMENT_ID) AS DOC_CC_COUNT FROM V_DOC_COUNT WHERE DOCUMENT_ID <= ?DOC_ID_VALUE? AND RECEIVE = ?RECEIVE_VALUE?));
```

phase 3:

```
SELECT QTY FROM DOC_COUNT where SEND= ?SEND_VALUE? AND RECEIVE = ?RECEIVE_VALUE?;
```

How can I retrieve the value QTY after it was updated/insert without using SELECT FROM MERGE statement (unfortunately, my DB2 version is not supporting that feature) and without concurrency issues?

Comment: Db2 version and platform? Have you looked into the ẀITH RR clause of MERGE?

Comment: My Db2 version is 9.7.0.6, currently installed on a Linux OS. How can I use the WITH RR clause in my statement?

Comment: Do you observe that other transactions can update, insert, or select from the table even though it's locked in the exclusive mode?

Comment: @mustaccio, I'm observing that after locking the table, I cannot proceed to phase 3 because the table DOC_COUNT is locked. So I would like to get the value after it inserted/updated but without concurrency violation (by other transactions)

Comment: Statements are not affected by locks created by the same transaction; does it mean that you run your phase 3 `select` in a different transaction from phase 1 and 2 statements?

Comment: @mustaccio, I think I found the problem. I was using these statements inside Informatica Power Center Designer, that's why I had some troubles with them. I changed the Transformation Scope of the SQL Transformation from "row" to "transaction" and everything went fine.